# compare list items against another list

Tags: python-2.7

So lets say I have 3 item list:

```
myString = "prop zebra cool"
items = myString.split(" ")
#items = ["prop", "zebra", "cool"]
```

And another list ***content*** containing hudreds of string items. Its actally a list of files.

Now I want to get only the items of ***content*** that contain all of the ***items***

So I started this way:

```
assets = []
for c in content:
    for item in items:
        if item in c:
            assets.append(c)
```

And then somehow isolate only the items that are duplicated in ***assets*** list

And this would work fine. But I dont like that, its not elegant. And Im sure that there is some other way to deal with that in python

Comment: What would be the output in this case that you are looking for? For some list `content`

Comment: well list would be most useful

Comment: If `items = ["prop", "zebra", "cool"]` and `content = ["prop"]` what would be the output?

Comment: no in this case     *content = ["z:/prop/zebra/rig/cool_v001.ma", "sjasdjaskkk", "thisIsNoGood", "shakalaka", "z:/prop/zebra/rig/cool_v999.ma"]*

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question correctly, you can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all).

In your case, assuming:

```
content = [
    "z:/prop/zebra/rig/cool_v001.ma",
    "sjasdjaskkk",
    "thisIsNoGood",
    "shakalaka",
    "z:/prop/zebra/rig/cool_v999.ma"
]
string = "prop zebra cool"
```

You can do the following:

```
assets = []
matchlist = string.split(' ')
for c in content:
    if all(s in c for s in matchlist):
        assets.append(c)
print assets
```

**Alternative Method**

If you want to have more control (ie. you want to make sure that you only match strings where your words appear in the specified order), then you could go with regular expressions:

```
import re

# convert content to a single, tab-separated, string
contentstring = '\t'.join(content)
# generate a regex string to match
matchlist = [r'(?:{0})[^\t]+'.format(s) for s in string.split(' ')]
matchstring = r'([^\t]+{0})'.format(''.join(matchlist))

assets = re.findall(matchstring, contentstring)
print assets
```

Assuming `\t` does not appear in the strings of `content`, you can use it as a separator and join the list into a single string (obviously, you can pick any other separator that better suits you).

Then you can build your regex so that it matches any substring containing your words and any other character, except `\t`.

In this case, `matchstring` results in:
`([^\t]+(?:prop)[^\t]+(?:zebra)[^\t]+(?:cool)[^\t]+)`
where:

- `(?:word)` means that `word` is matched but not returned
- `[^\t]+` means that all characters but `\t` will match
- the outer `()` will return whole strings matching your rule (in this case `z:/prop/zebra/rig/cool_v001.ma` and `z:/prop/zebra/rig/cool_v999.ma`)